# How do I convert special chars of passwords typed with CAPSLOCK?

Tags: javascript, php, string

If someone has pressed CAPSLOCK while typing the password,

```
abcXYZ123
```

will result in

abcXYZ123

(or maybe `ABCxyz!"§` on some OS?)

How can I convert this correctly?

with [mb_strtolower()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strtolower.php) I can only convert it all to lowercase.
With:

```
mb_strtolower('ABCxyz!"§');
```

the numbers are not restored:

```
abcxyz!"§
```

Comment: Why would you convert this at all? How do you distinguish between somebody *wanting* to type `ABCxyz!"§` from somebody accidentally having had caps lock on? Also, caps lock acts very differently across different systems. Shift+1 does not yield "!" on all keyboards, not all systems yield "!" when pressing "1" with caps lock on.

Comment: I'd suggest to give a hint to a user rather than converting the characters automatically.

Comment: I tried to detect the damage already done: if someone had used CAPS when creating his password

Comment: When you have capslock turned on you will NOT get `ABCxyz!"§` when typing `abcXYZ123`.

Comment: its not a clear logic of your requirement.

Comment: If Caplock is on and number are entered, they stay number? Shift on the other hand will give that problem. In which case that the users problem and they should be prompted to try again.

Comment: The logic is clear but it is not possible. The maximum you can do is to detect weather caps lock has been pressed and give a warning to the user. But with JavaScript, not with PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just show message about capslock when user entering it and dont care... You cant detect if user use capslock or not in server side.

fast sample how you can detect when user enter char:

```
$('#password').keypress(function(e) { 
    var s = String.fromCharCode( e.which );
    if ( s.toUpperCase() === s && s.toLowerCase() !== s && !e.shiftKey ) {
        alert('caps is on');
    }
```

Comment: alert on caps on. Thats not good idea. What if i really have upper case password?

Comment: just replace alert to your code and show custom message or hint

Comment: @rookieB look at sample again please with atention

Comment: This has the same problem as the code of the OP: `'!'.toLowerCase()` does not equal `'1'`.

Comment: @Vladimir On my current system it doesn't either, no. But I seem to remember that on some systems it did. I don't remember how long ago that was, but I imagine some versions of Windows work that way.

Comment: @deceze hm... i dont remember systems like this.. i think we must start support ie1 again in that case ;)

Comment: Your script works fine on ubuntu. Thanks, that is really helpful

Comment: I used a `<div id="warning">` and then `$('#warning').html("caps is on");` instead of alert.

Answer (score 1):

As I already said in the comments, you can't do what you wonna do.

To update and end all this, I have to tell you, that you can't even reliable check weather caps lock has been pressed.

Simple proof:

Head to jQuery .keypress manual page: http://api.jquery.com/keypress/

Go to the very bottom and press a key. Press caps lock then.

**caps lock does not trigger a key pressed event and does not have its own keyCode**

*-fin-*